# execute php script from within another php script every "x" seconds

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to save a live camera image locally on the server every 30 seconds while the php page is active.

I am currently using this code below which works fine in bringing in the current live image on page load:

```
exec('php -q /path/to/file/saveimage.php');
```

The problem I am having is getting the above code to run every 30 seconds. I've tried a few different attempts with ajax/jQuery but couldn't get them to work.

Seems like it should be pretty straight forward since all it needs to do is execute the .php, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You mean something like this? `<script>setInterval(function(){$.get('/path/to/file/saveimage.php');},30000);</script>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to show some of the jQuery that you've tried so far. (Unless Tim's suggestion has already solved the problem?)

Comment: I'm testing Tim's solution now, but can't seem to get it to work. Removing the code in the original question and replacing with the script is giving me a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in..."

Comment: Thanks, for this. It did work. I do have a follow up question should I post here or a new question all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim said:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('/path/to/file/saveimage.php');
    }, 30000);
</‌​script>
```